# flex: can i do nice button animation using only flex or do i need adobe flash too?

Tags: apache-flex, animation

i would like to add nice animations and other graphics to my application. do i need to use flash to create partial swf files and to load them or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do a lot of animations in Flex (although I haven't done anything very complex yet).  You should check out [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

Even though Flex offers some [TweenEffects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/TweenEffect.html) (check the list of subclasses), I'd say that animations are better done in Flash CS3/4 as it offers more control on drawing and frames.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should have said ***basic*** animations